# Why can't typescript maintain types in Array.prototype.filter()?

Tags: typescript

The following code is fine but if you uncomment the last line ts will give an error. Seems like .filter() throws away the already inferred type from the previous step which doesn't make sense to me. Please explain how ts works here and suggest a solution.

```
type ItemIds =
    | 'foo'
    | 'bar';

interface Item {
    id: ItemIds;
};

const items: Item[] = [
    {
        id: 'foo',
    },
    {
        id: 'bar',
    }
]
//.filter((item) => true)
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsYBMDOUC8AoKuoB8oByAMwHsyic9CiAjAQwCciBuLLASwDt4mSGAY2hxEUAN7VcnZAC5Y8JGnYBfdlkFluqYFE6LU80QgDaAXUxQTUiTbx65xcpQA0NlW-uT79mfPrMRJ54KlhmWAD0EVAAdCScADZ8ABTJ+ogAlJgAfFDATACuEBlAA

Answer (score 3):

When you assign the literal array to `items`, even though the type of the literal is `{id: string;}[]` (not `[id: "foo" | "bar";]{}` aka `Item[]`), TypeScript can see that all the `id` values fit into `"foo" | "bar"` so it allows the assignment to occur.

However, if you call `.filter` on that array, it can't do that anymore. The type of the array is `{id: string;}[]`, so that's the result of `filter`. It can't know that `filter` doesn't modify `id` values, it just knows that the types for `filter` say it will return an array of the same type. Which is `{id: string;}[]`, not `{id: "foo" | "bar";}[]` (`Item[]`).

If you ensure that the array you're calling `filter` on has the type `Item[]`, it will work:

```
const items = ([
    {
        id: 'foo',
    },
    {
        id: 'bar',
    }
] as Item[])
.filter((item) => true);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=1&pln=17&pc=25#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsYBMDOUC8AoKuoB8oByAMwHsyic9CiAjAQwCciBuLLASwDt4mSGAY2hxEUAN7VcnZAC5Y8JGnYBfdlkFluqYFE6L0GKAAoA2lIkW8eucXKUANBZVPrk69Znz6zIq7wqWAC6UAzoogimQQCUWAB0JJwANnzGxvqI0ZgAfFDATACuENGsQA)

Answer (score 2):

It would maintain static typing if you were to declare your starting array as `Item[]`, eg.:

```
const items: Item[] = [
    {
        id: 'foo',
    },
    {
        id: 'bar',
    }
]

const filteredItems: Item[] = items.filter(item => true)
```

The issue is with the string union type `ItemIds`, as it's interpreted as `string` without you telling the compiler otherwise.

The same issue comes up if you just let the compiler infer the type of `items` first, then reassign it:

```
// This wont compile either.
const items = [
    {
        id: 'foo',
    },
    {
        id: 'bar',
    }
]

const typedItems: Item[] = items
```

Comment: I really like your example at the end, drills home the point that TypeScript can only check that all the `id`s fit the type when it has a literal to work with.

Answer (score 1):

It's because

```
[ { id: 'foo' }, { id: 'bar' }]
```

is still a `{ id: string } []` by the time you filter.

There's two approaches to this:

1. process after

```
const items: Item[] = [
    {
        id: 'foo',
    },
    {
        id: 'bar',
    }
]
const filtered = items.filter((item) => true)
```

2. Cast before

```
const items: Item[] = ([
    {
        id: 'foo',
    },
    {
        id: 'bar',
    }
] as Item[])
.filter((item) => true)
```

With the second approach you don't need to explicitly state the type since it will be implied already

```
const items = ([
    {
        id: 'foo',
    },
    {
        id: 'bar',
    }
] as Item[])
.filter((item) => true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare `items` first

```
interface Item {
    id: ItemIds;
};

const items: Item[] = [
    {
        id: 'foo',
    },
    {
        id: 'bar',
    }
]
const filtered = items.filter((item) => true) // filtered has type Item[]
```

Comment: Well, you don't *have* to. :-) It would also be good to say *why* the problem occurs.